# jQuery events for appended content using .on?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have appended content (using ajax) to my document and my events are not firing. I know this can be done using .live() but I read somewhere that it's deprecated now?

This is my code (it works fine on document ready, but not on the newly appended items):

```
$('li[id^="inv-"] a.close').on('click', function(){
 var item=($(this).closest("li[id^='inv-']")).attr('id');
 var id = parseInt(item.replace("inv-", ""));
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "ajax-invi.php",
   dataType: "html",
   data: "id="+idboda+"&idinv="+id+"&borrar=ok",
   success: function(data) {
     noty({"text":"El invitado ha sido borrado"});
     $("body").find('li#inv-' + id).remove();
   }
  }); 
});
```

And the items:

```
<ul>
  <li id="inv-39">
   <div class="row_field">
     <label>Adri</label>
     <a class="close" href="#invlist">Borrar</a>
   </div>                  
  </li>
  <li id="inv-40">
   <div class="row_field">
     <label>Marga</label>
     <a class="close" href="#invlist">Borrar</a>
   </div>  
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` is the trick http://stackoverflow.com/a/9869024/880434

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
$('ul').on('click','a.close', function(){
 var item=($(this).closest("li[id^='inv-']")).attr('id');
 var id = parseInt(item.replace("inv-", ""));
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "ajax-invi.php",
   dataType: "html",
   data: "id="+idboda+"&idinv="+id+"&borrar=ok",
   success: function(data) {
     noty({"text":"El invitado ha sido borrado"});
     $("body").find('li#inv-' + id).remove();
   }
  }); 
});
```

in this way you delegate the event handling to the ul which is present when the DOM is loaded and handles the events of elements added through AJAX. If the ul is not present when the dom is loaded you could delegate to the `<body>`tag

EDIT - live() it's actually a wrapper around `on()` (before it was a wrapper around `delegate()`) but delegates the event handling usually to the `window` which means that the event has to bubble up a lot. Taken from jQuery source

```
live: function( types, data, fn ) {
    jQuery( this.context ).on( types, this.selector, data, fn );
    return this;
},
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I needed. I thought .on() would work like .live() does, why is this?

Comment: @ElaineMarley live() actually was a wrapper around delegate() (now is a wrapper around on()), any way i edited my  answer with some background

Comment: Thanks for the info, I needed to learn how to do this properly

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('click', 'li[id^="inv-"] a.close', function(){ 
//... 
});
```

So, you append event to some parent element, which looks for siblings which exists on page-loading and which will be appended in future.